# Prioritize color of emphasis faces in Org headers

Tags: org-mode, font-lock

Observe the following Org buffer, tested on Emacs with no configuration (`emacs -q`):

[image: org buffer with emphasis markers]

Note that **bold**, **italic**, and **underline** are all distinctly fontified in the header. However **verbatim** and **code** are not.

This becomes more relevant when viewing Org-mode buffers with emphasis markers hidden, with `(setq org-hide-emphasis-markers t)`:

[image]

Now **code** and **verbatim** emphasis is not visible. I would rather that the foreground color of `org-code` and `org-verbatim` be given priority over the foreground color of `org-level-1`. How may I achieve this?

> *Version Information*:
>   **Org**: Org mode version 9.2.3 (9.2.3-20-g31873e-elpa)
>   **Emacs**: GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.10)

Comment: Tested with emacs -q 26.2 and org 9.1.9. Both code and verbatim are fontified as expected. Your example is especially strange as the 3rd should be italic and not underlined or did you customize the font? Once upon a time, I encounter strange stuff with org. What usually helps is to recompile it or just delete the folder completely and reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this in Emacs 28.0.50. Emacs displays the line you have given in the same colors regardless of whether `org-hide-emphasis-markers` is set to `t` or `nil`. Hence, `org-code` and `org-verbatim` are given priority over the foreground color of `org-level-1`. (They are shown in grey not blue.) With `org-hide-emphasis-markers` set to `t` what is not visible are the symbols `=` and `~`. But perhaps I am misunderstanding what you are asking.